# Как сохранить файлы (pdf) в файловой системе сервера в jsf

Tags: файлы, java-ee, servlet, файловая-система, glassfish

Думал, хранить в базе данных, но там тип longblob занимает только 1Мб, да и производительность будет низкой. Вопрос в шапке.Хотелось, чтобы пользователи могли сохранять в папку resources,пробовал также сохранять, но файлы почему-то сохраняются не там, где надо + с перезапуском glassfish все пропадает. Помогите!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class DemoBean 
{
    private Part file1;
    private Part file2;

    private static String DIR = null;
    public Part getFile1()
    {
        return file1;
    }

    public void setFile1(Part file1)
    {
        this.file1 = file1;
    }

    public Part getFile2()
    {
        return file2;
    }

    public void setFile2(Part file2) {
        this.file2 = file2;
    }

    private static void setDirUpload()
    {
        ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext)FacesContext
                                               .getCurrentInstance()
                                               .getExternalContext()
                                               .getContext();
        String path = servletContext.getRealPath("/");
        File fl = new File(path + "/upload");
        DIR = fl.getPath() + File.separator;
    }
    public String upload() throws IOException
    {
        if (DIR == null)
            setDirUpload();
        System.out.println(DIR + getFilename(file2));
        file1.write(getFilename(file1));
        file2.write(getFilename(file2));

        return "success?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    private static String getFilename(Part part) 
    {
        for (String file : part.getHeader("content-disposition")
                               .split(";")) {
            if (file.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
                String filename = file.substring(file.indexOf('=') + 1)
                                      .trim().replace("\"", "");
                return filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
                                              .substring(filename
                                              .lastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}


 <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p><h:inputFile value="#{demoBean.file1}" style="width:400px;" /></p>

            <p><h:inputFile value="#{demoBean.file2}" style="width:400px;" /></p>
            <h:commandButton value="Загрузить" action="#{demoBean.upload}"/>
        </h:form>
```

Comment: Пример кода как сохраняете выложите

Comment: Сохранять нужно в webapps.

Comment: дополнил описание вопроса

Comment: `DIR = servletContext.getRealPath("/../upload/");` создай папку upload в webapps

Comment: Тип longblob в MySQL позволяет хранить до 4 ГБ

Comment: спасибо большое, помогли)

Comment: что про longblob скажете?

Comment: я решил не сохранять в БД. Думаю, если буду грузить 20+Мб, и получать в виде pdf, то много времени уйдет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

создайте папку upload в webapps

```
DIR = servletContext.getRealPath("/../upload/");
```

Comment: у меня glassfish 5.0, я никак не могу найти эту папку webapps, может тут другой корень?

Comment: @ЕльцовДанил посмотри что этот метод возвращает `servletContext.getRealPath("/");`